# Building Android Email app

Tags: android, git, email

I was thinking about checking out some of the built-in Android apps, since they are opensource, so i donwloaded from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Email
the code and imported the project in eclipse.
I tried to build the project but i get errors. Do i need some kind of prerequisites?

Here's the error - in tempStorage.java i get "String cannot be resolved to a type", and in the console "[2012-10-19 13:47:20 - AndroidMail] Project has no project.properties file! Edit the project properties to set one."

What should i do? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to build the ASOP Applications using eclipse directly. They use advanced features for building which can not be handled directly using the eclipse build process. Also the projects are not stand-alone but have cross-dependencies (see below)

The only straight solution for building the EMail (and all other) ASOP Applications is to check out the whole Android Source Tree ([see here for a howto](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html)) and then use the build in build process using the make files. You can build the EMail application using "make EMail" in the folder where you checked out the source tree. You might need to set up a build environment first.

Theoretically it is possible to turn the source into a working eclipse project. I did this some months ago. What you need to do, is to identify all cross-dependencies of the EMail Application (check the Makefile `Android.mk` for this). If I remeber correctly, there are at least two of them ([framework/ex/chips](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/ex/) and [frameworks/opt/mailcommon](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/mailcommon/)). You also need to check them out and convert them into a working Android Library project. Then modify the EMail application to include the newly created Android Libraries. But: This is far from an easy solution and requires multiple modifications. The way described above is the way to go.